# Adcionar widget na tela inicial

Tags: java, android, widget

Estou usando a biblioteca

https://github.com/prolificinteractive/material-calendarview

E estou quase no final do projeto, mas agora tenho a necessidade de inserir a opção de widget do calendário, mas o layout do calendário não aparece.

Fica uma tela preta informando problema na exibição

Código do Layout:

```
<com.prolificinteractive.materialcalendarview.MaterialCalendarView android:id="@+id/calendarView" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Aguardo comentários.

Answer (score 0):

Já vi que não é posssivel.

https://github.com/prolificinteractive/material-calendarview/issues/41

Mas se alguém tiver sugestões agradeço.